# A free WYSIWYG control for DotNet

Tags: .net, winforms, controls

I search a free and easy to drag&drop in my winform WYSIWYG-Control.

The background is, I don't have time I can spend on the control, it must be there and ready.

DotNet.2 C#
NO ASP!
WinForm!

Comment: WYSIWYG what? Text (word processing?), graphics (vector graphics? charts?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's the [ModelText HTML Control for .NET](http://www.modeltext.com/html/), which is a WYSIWYG control for Windows Forms on .NET version 2 (i.e. what you're asking for).

If you try it, please let me know how well it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this one:
http://winformhtmltextbox.codeplex.com/

Works great for me.

Comment: Link is broken, codeplex is dead